# Events on PHP. Is it possible?

Tags: php, events, language-features

I'm coming from the C# world and has just started doing a little PHP coding, so I was wondering if it is possible to use events on PHP, or if it is planned to include this feature in a future release. If you have a way to simulate it, different than [this](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Simulating-Events-with-PHP-5/), it would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: ey sorry, but I didn't understand ur comment... I am not english speaker so I ask for appologies if i have made a mistake

Comment: You can use function pointers to implement crude event handling, but you'll be disappointed if you're expecting the fit-and-finish of C# delegates.

Comment: Yeah event handling will be crude at best. Keep your expectations low.

Comment: @Earlz - I think you meant Variable Functions. Jhonny, check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php the second example, "Example #2 Variable method example" might help you.

Comment: @Richard, Nice trick to add to the toolbox :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No event like C# in PHP but you can implement a [Observer Pattern](http://devzone.zend.com/article/5) to attach delegate to be notified.

Answer (score 2):

The [Prado PHP Framework](http://www.pradosoft.com/) is an event driven framework that may appeal to you, especially since you are coming from the land of C# and presumably ASP.NET.

Take a look at the [Quick Start](http://www.pradosoft.com/demos/quickstart/). Specifically, take a look at the code under the Control Reference. There are plenty of code samples for you to look at and see if it is something like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Stubbles has a pretty nice [Event Dispatcher](http://stubbles.net/wiki/Docs/EventHandling).

Answer (score 1):

SPL - the [Standard PHP Library](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/main.html) provides the [SplObserver](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceSplObserver.html) and [SplSubject](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceSplSubject.html) interfaces for implementing the observer pattern in PHP

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Prado as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like event handling class in PHP :

```
class Event {
    protected $_eventCallbacks = array();
    function addEventCallback($callback) {
        $this->_eventCallbacks[$callback] = $callback;
    }
    function removeEventCallback($callback){
        if(isset($this->_eventCallbacks[$callback])){
            unset ($this->_eventCallbacks[$callback]);
        }
    }
    function cleanEventCallback(){
        foreach ($this->_eventCallbacks as $callback) {
            unset ($callback);
        }
    }
    function fireEvent() {
        foreach ($this->_eventCallbacks as $callback) {
            call_user_func($callback);
        }
    }
}
```

This code was taken from here http://setahost.com/php-events-singletone-and-factory-pattern-application/
There is also good example of modular and sub modular application using this class .